# Discord.py Google search giving random stuff I don't need

Tags: google-api, discord.py

```
@bot.command(name='what_is')
async def what_is(ctx, *, query):
search_query = f'What is {query}'

try:
    # Perform a Google search
    results = list(search(search_query, num=1, stop=1, pause=2))
    if results:
        await ctx.send(f"Here is what I found: {results[0]}")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Sorry, I couldn't find any information.")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    await ctx.send("An error occurred while searching.")
```

This is a code block for a google search. But whenever I search something up it gives me from images to just straight up random bs. Idk if this is problem with the API or query [here is an image of a result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR0NP.png)

Comment: btw please ignore indentation error, Idk how to very properly edit block of code in stackoverflow, all of my indents are perfect in the real code

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks about formatting code when posting questions. Unfortunately, the programming language you're using (appears to be Python) is indentation sensitive. So it needs to be posted correctly to know exactly what code you tried to run.

Comment: Where is `search` defined? It looks like it might be relevant to the problem you're experiencing. Is it another function you've defined? Is it from a library? Is it from Discord.py or some other library that you happen to also be using? Showing the complete code will make it easier to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what library you are using but I used `googlesearch` and it worked with your code and some modifications.

Pip: `pip install googlesearch`
Import: `from googlesearch import search`

Code:

```
@bot.command(name='what_is')
async def what_is(ctx, *, query):
    search_query = f'What is {query}'

    try:
        results = list(search(search_query,num_results=1,lang='en',sleep_interval=0,timeout=10))
        if results:
            await ctx.send(f"Here is what I found: {results[0]}")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Sorry, I couldn't find any information.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await ctx.send("An error occurred while searching.")
```